# How to view the profile of an employee using Laravel and JWT in API

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table User with column

```
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('emp_id');
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->string('password');
```

And table Employee

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('employee_id')->unique();
$table->string('employee_name');
$table->string('department');
$table->string('designation');
$table->string('supervisor');
$table->string('hr_master');
$table->timestamps();
```

When the first time i logged in using JWT, i have emp_id from User is foreign key to Employee table. I want to view the profile of the employee using emp_id in table User to get the information of that employee in Employee table. This is the function i write

```
public function getEmployeeDetail(){
        return $this->user->employee()
        ->first()->toArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first create a relation in your User model

```
public function employee()
{

return $this->hasOne(Employee::class,'emp_id','id');

}
```

now for call it

```
$user=auth()->user();
$user->employee //out put = curent Employee detail
```

Comment: it returns the information in the User table, not the Employee table :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to `App/User` model.

```
public function getEmployeeAttribute()
{
    return \App\Employee::find($this->emp_id);
}
```

After that you can access the related `App\Employee` data like this:

```
$user->employee->employee_name
```

And you can use [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional) helper function to prevent causing an error if user not related to any employee:

```
optional($user->employee)->employee_name
```

Comment: i will try this one

Comment: so the line $user->employee->employee_name will be put into the EmployeeController right?

Comment: The accessor can be used anywhere if the $user variable is an App/User instance.